# Квитанция на оплату налоги или об оплате налоги

Tags: грамматика

If I'm emailing the bank to ask for a receipt for a payment and want to sound formal, what should I use? What would sound most natural?

Прошу вас прислать квитанцию на оплату налоги(обучение....)

Answer (score 8):

Прошу вас прислать квитанцию об уплате налога (оплате обучения).

It's usually "квитанция об..." (**about** a payment that's been made) and "счёт на..." (**for** an expected payment).

The choice between оплата/уплата:

- If you're talking about money (сумма, налог), use уплата (чего?) суммы, налога; уплатить (что?) сумму, налог.
- If you state what you're paying *for*, use оплата/оплатить: оплата обучения, оплатить проживание.

Comment: Got it. In this case I am asking for the document with all the info to go to the bank and pay for my education. So ..прислать счет на оплату обучения. .... прислать счеть на обучение.